# Detecting ReactJS Page Changes

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS so have been experimenting on some sites that use it. Right now, I'm trying to make an AJAX call to an API based on a pages URL. The problem is that whenever a link is clicked, my code breaks because it's not detecting a page change. My current approach is to listen for click events on all links and piggyback off two selectors I see appear when the page is loading (pageLoading--loading and pageLoading--finished). Is there a better way to detect page changes for single page applications? For situation reference since these are experiments, I have no access to the server. Below is my current code approach.

```
//When any link on the page is clicked
document.body.onclick = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  var from = findParent('a',e.target || e.srcElement);
  if (from){
    //check if pageLoading--finished ran then make an AJAX request
    console.log(__reactContent['url']);
  }
}
//find first parent with tagName [tagname]
function findParent(tagname,el){
  if ((el.nodeName || el.tagName).toLowerCase()===tagname.toLowerCase()){
    return el;
  }
  while (el = el.parentNode){
    if ((el.nodeName || el.tagName).toLowerCase()===tagname.toLowerCase()){
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your component in which you are facing issue? this looks like vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setState`. That way react will notice page changes and handle events. Here's a quick example of adding new notes to a notes array.

```
addNote = () => {
        this.setState({
            notes: this.state.notes.concat([{
                id: uuid.v4(),
                task: 'new task'
            }])
        })
    }
```

For some more info check out https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html